# Find Model by filtering it's List<other class>((Stream Filter)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, stream, java-stream

I want to list out all Device_Type that have Device_Telemetry name start with "Process".

Device_Type.Class (Field of Device_Type collection)

```
@NotBlank
private String applicationId;
private AcnDeviceCategory deviceCategory;
private boolean editable = CoreConstant.DEFAULT_EDITABLE;
private List<DeviceTelemetry> telemetries = new ArrayList<>();
private Map<String, DeviceStateValueMetadata> stateMetadata = new HashMap<>();
private List<DeviceAction> actions = new ArrayList<>();
```

DeviceTelemetry.Class

```
private String name;
private String description;
@NotNull
private TelemetryItemType type;
private String telemetryUnitId;
private Map<String, String> variables = new HashMap<>();
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can either collect to a list or use streams:

collect to a list:

```
public static List<DeviceTelemetry> getWithProcess() {
    List<DeviceTelemetry> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (DeviceTelemetry telemetry : telemetries) {
        if (telemetry.name.startsWith("Process"))
            result.add(telemetry)
    }
    return result;
}
```

stream:

```
public static List<DeviceTelemetry> getWithProcess() {
    List<DeviceTelemetry> result = telemetries.stream()
            .filter(telemetry->telemetry.name.startsWith("Process"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return result;
}
```